# Validation (HTML5) Element 'Title' occurs too few time

Tags: html

I'm busy making my own website. I have the following as a homepage but I get the warning. Element 'title' occurs too few times. I would also like to know how you can do word rap, I want the text to fit neatly in the web browser window. It is not an error only a warning but I would like to know what it means.

[image: Error]

```html
<head>
<link href="CSS/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>FORM</title>
    <link href="../CSS/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<table style="height: 92px; float: left;" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="Form/HtmlPage1.html">Form</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;"><a href="ContactDetails/ContactDetails.html">Contact Details</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="About/About.html">About</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="MusicalHereos/MusicalHereos.html">Musical Hereos</a> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp; <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>MY TEACHING PHILOSOPHY:</strong></span></p>
<p>&nbsp; I would like to take this opportunity to introduce myself and what I do for a</p>
<p>&nbsp; living. I'm a music teacher specializing in Music Theory education, I also teach</p>
<p>&nbsp; Guitar to a lesser extent.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>I have been teaching since 2014 and in these last couple of years, I have learned a few things.</p>
<p>There is no reason Innate to a child that decides music ability. No child or person is born with</p>
<p>some sort of gift where the other is not. Being 'Tone Deaf' is a myth, if a teacher tells a child he</p>
<p>cannot do music then it speaks more to the teacher's inability than the child's ability.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Music, for the most part, is just another trade. If a child is taught well and puts in the hours he or</p>
<p>she can become proficient in his or her instrument. I don't believe in talent, I believe in hard work.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>When natural born 'talent' has little to do with music, what has a profound effect on the progress of</p>
<p>the musician is the attitude and the work ethic. Children who are motivated and especially those who</p>
<p>motivate themselves will succeed where those who are stubborn and lazy will not.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>I teach both Guitar and Music Theory, I can teach both the Rock and Classical styles. I also insist that </p>
<p>my students do Music Theory as part of their training as it is important for there continued development.</p>
<p>I was raised on the rock music of the early 2000's. The pop-punk genre was a big part of my childhood. </p>
<p>I eventually graduated from popular music and found the wonderful world of classical music. My love for </p>
<p>the guitar grew further as I fell in love with this fascinating part of the guitar world. I eventually </p>
<p>came to know the great Andres Segovia and what he meant for the development of </p>
<p>the guitar as instrument.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>The guitar to me is the most beautiful of instruments, in all of it's forms it fascinates me. The electric version just </p>
<p>as much as the acoustic version. With the electric version there is a power to move you that is simply tremendous.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>All music gets us to move, that is why music and dance have such a rich history together, but with the electric guitar,</p>
<p>it is even more the case. When you stand in the crowd in front of those wall of Marshalls and you can feel the speaker cabinets</p>
<p>literally move the air around you. You feel the air thumping against you chest it moves you on a primitive, visceral level. When</p>
<p>the gods decided to add electricity to the guitar, music was made anew.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>The acoustic guitar in both it's steel and nylon string variants fascinates me on another level. The acoustic guitar</p> 
<p>to me has a purity of tone. It also has a richness in harmonics, that is why a guitar can sound wonderful even when only few </p>
<p>notes are played. 
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>The acoustic guitar is the instrument set between a piano and a violin. With it's six strings </p>
<p>it can play chords in a manner resembling the piano somewhat, but when it comes to dynamical qualities it resembles the violin.</p>
<p>You can do vibrato just like a violin and you can even do bends which is unique to the guitar. All of this gives you </p>
<p>an instrument with some siilarities with others and still enough things particular to it, to make it unique.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>
<link href="CSS/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>FORM</title>
    <link href="../CSS/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
```

You should merge duplicated `head` section. The parser do not see `<title>` tag in the first one. Also notice `<head>` **must be** child of `<html>`.

Answer (score 1):

for word wrap add in css

`style="word-wrap: break-word;"`